# Windows 10 startmenu: Adding submenues like in Win7 School-PC

Tags: startmenu

Short and dirty: My IT-school got their Windows 7 to be fairly minimalized, which I dig a lot. In particular, their starmenu consisted of nothing more than several subfolders leading to programs (shortcuts of them, rather).

I don't want to completely strip Windows 10's startmenu, I do wonder if something like this was possible though. I've tried googling this idea, but I've only found ways of adding tiles leading to folders - which isn't my intention. I want to be able to open a submenu (let it be folders, even) that allow me to access shortcuts without having to open the folder in the File Explorer.

Comment: This isn't a general tech helpdesk.

Comment: Oh, is it not? I've seen plenty of people ask similar questions before, hence why I posted it up here. I could've sworn this was Windows 10 related before I've sent this one out. Regardless, I've asked a 1-way question that applies to the rules, unless I've understood them improperly.

Comment: You've understood them improperly. This site's for questions about programming; see the [tour].

Comment: How about telling me exactly how I did? It would be more constructive this way. By giving such vague replies, you're breaking a rule yourself: Discussion.

Comment: Sorry, hit enter too early; comment's updated. Not clear why you think *"Discussion"* is a rule, though; in general it should be avoided in favour of clear, on topic questions.

Comment: Oh, here we go! That explains a lot. Though not any of the related topics sounded close to my issue by title, digging into them revealed programming code all over. Point taken, I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Classicshell for Win 10, 8 and 7.   You can customize the menu any way you like with it and ClassicShell is free.

[ClassicShell.net](http://classicshell.net)

i.e.   This ClassicShell is setup on my Windows 2012R2.   Although the screenshot is Windows 2012R2, it works, just the same for Windows 7 and newer, including server OSs.

[ClassicShell Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0mQl.jpg)

Comment: checking it out right now - I feel like his can give me what it needs, if that's the case, then I'll make our reply the wrap-up-solution. Thanks a bunch for suggesting it! :)

Comment: I like it because i get full control of the Start Menu.   There is a check box that expands the settings and there are plenty of options.   You can add a "custom" item to the Start Menu that can really link to anything.    I use it to link to specific files and websites, etc...    I have used this for myself and at least 100 clients.   Some computer users need super simple and some super complex.  ClassicShell gives you all the options.